# Properties of a functional on $\ell^\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis

For $\Phi: \ell^\infty \to \mathbb R$ a linear map, consider the following three properties:

(a): $\Phi$ sends the constant sequence $(c, c, \ldots)$ to $c$;

(b): $\Phi(x)\ge 0$ whenever $x \ge 0$

(c): $| \Phi(x)|\le \| x \|.$

How to prove that $(a)+(b)$ is equivalent to $(a)+(c)$?

Comment: $x$ is a sequence, that means $x \geq 0$?

Comment: @Ilovemath: in this context it means entrywise, as the notion agrees with positivity when one sees $\ell^\infty$ as a C$^*$-algebra.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you are considering only real sequences.

If you have (a)+(b), take any $x$. Then $(\|x\|\pm x_1,\|x\|\pm x_2,\ldots)\geq0$. This tells us that
$$
0\leq\Phi(\|x\|\pm x_1,\|x\|\pm x_2,\ldots)=\|x\|\pm\Phi(x).
$$
Thus $|\Phi(x)|\leq\|x\|$.

For the converse, suppose that $\|x\|\leq1$ and $x\geq0$. So $0\leq x_j\leq 1$ for all $j$. Then $-1\leq 2x_j-1\leq 1$. This shows that $\|2x-1\|\leq1$. Thus
$$
|2\Phi(x)-1|=|\phi(2x-1)|\leq1. 
$$
Unwinding the above,
$$
0\leq\Phi(x)\leq 1,
$$
and $\Phi(x)\geq0$. Now for arbitrary $x$ we apply the above to $x/\|x\|$.

With a bit more work, the result also applies to the case of complex sequences.

Comment: Thank you very much. There is something I don't get in the implication (a)+(b) implies (c): $\Phi(x)\le \lvert \lvert x \rvert \rvert$, so...?

Comment: It can also done with plus, if that's what you mean. I have edited that.